# java creating a method of one class that calls method of another class

Tags: java, class, methods

*I've* been given a task that has a lot of restrictions on how it is completed and have spent the entire day trying to solve it and it feels like I am going to get nowhere with this unless I seek help.

I will first mention that the following code MUST stay the same. More methods can be added but the current methods and attributes must remain the same.

All I want todo is take a date: day month and year, from the console input(must be done in main method), which will then be stored in the "date" object (this can be played around with). Date object then calls get Day() method which will return an integer between 0-6. I now want to create a method called getDayOfWeek() which will take the integer value between 0-6 and return an actual a day of the week (Saturday for example). I don't need help creating the functionality of the getDayOfWeek() method.. i'm just having problems working out how i would parse that integer value into the function. I've tried countless things.. for example I'm trying to imaging this working:

getDayOfWeek(){

switch(date.getDay()) ect..

The error reads "cannot find symbol: variable date, location: MyCalendar2"
I've tried to describe the scenario as best and as detailed I can. Thanks to anyone who can help.

```
package mycalendar2;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyCalendar2 {

private MyDate myDate2;
static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Enter the date as day month year: ");
    int d = scanner.nextInt();
    int m = scanner.nextInt();
    int y = scanner.nextInt();

    MyDate date = new MyDate(d, m, y);
}

public MyCalendar2(myDate x){
    this.myDate2 = x;
}

  public int getDayOfWeek(){
   switch(date.getDay()) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Day is a Sunday");
        break;
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Day is a Monday");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Day is a Tuesday");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Day is a Wednesday");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Day is a Thursday");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Day is a Friday");
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("Day is a Saturday");
            break;
        default:
            break;
         }
       }
      }


class MyDate{

private int day;
private int month;
private int year;

public MyDate(int d, int m, int y){
    this.day = d;
    this.month = m;
    this.year = y;
}

public int getDay(){
    int y0 = year - (14 - month) / 12;
    int x = y0 + y0 / 4 - y0 / 100 + y0 / 400;
    int m0 = month + 12 * ((14 - month) / 12) - 2;
    int d0 = (day + x + (31 * m0) / 12) % 7;

    return d0;

}
}
```

Comment: it doesn't as this doesn't recognise "date" object, why it should not? Honestly, i did not get you what you want.

Comment: Please show us the code that is not working and what do and why you think is not working, or the error you had if there is an error.

Comment: don't do that. ``MyDate`` kind of classes are _always_ a bad idea. Use ``java.time.LocalDate`` or at least ``java.util.Date``. Do not reinvent the wheel. Dates are difficult to handle correctly (even core java developpers had a few issues with their first attempt in java.util)

Comment: Its a small part of a very large assignment I have no choice. Anyway @MarioSantini i have edited as you wished

Comment: @tom the bigger the assignement comes, the more important it is not to take bad decisions. Reinventing date tools is broken by design. You won't be able to reach sufficient quality. It will have bugs. It will lack some essential functionnality. It is not your fault. It is because dates _are_ difficult. Don't -spend- waste time trying to reimplement it. Use this time to learn standard API (only exception: you are a student and this is part of your process to learn java syntax).

Comment: @tom Are you sure the methods *must* stay the same? This code won't compile since the signature of the method `getDayOfWeek`, for instance, requires and int to be returned; yet it doesn't. Also, why is it a requirement that the methods must stay the same?

Comment: Can getDayOfWeek() be like getDayOfWeek(MyDate date) ?

Comment: `date` cannot be found because it is nowhere declared. It isn't a field, it isn't a local variable, it isn't a parameter. If you use `myDate2` instead of `date` in `getDayOfWeek()` you'll not get the error, since `myDate2` is a field. But there are still other compile time errors (at least in the shown code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have mentioned the code must remain same.

You can try this approach,

1. You have MyCalendar2 constructor, but haven't created the MyCalendar2 Object.
2. After creating the MyDate date = new MyDate(d, m, y); object, you can create MyCalendar2 object with this "date" object.
3. Then, you can access the getDayOfWeek and print the day.
4. There are some syntax errors, use the MyCalendar2 myDate2 object inside the method and also change the return type of getDayOfWeek as void.
5. And the constructor has to be like this public MyCalendar2(MyDate x) not public MyCalendar2(myDate x).

Hope it helps.